# ResponseEntityExceptionHandler does not send an error code to the client despite @ResponseStatus annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, exceptionhandler

I want to prevent spring from sending complete stacktrace of Runtimexceptions to the front end. I did something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception e, Object body, 
               HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        logger.error("Error happened while executing controller.", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

My objective is to send just the error code and nothing else to the front end. The above method returns status 200 OK to front end. What should be returned instead of null ?

Comment: Everything that can be casted to `ResponseEntity<Object>`

Comment: @RomanC Yes, I just tried returning new ResponseEntity<Object>("Error", status) and it worked. Why it does not work with null ? Even with new ResponseEntity<Object>(null, status), it returns 200 OK. Thanks!

Comment: What if you add a reason: `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "test")`?

Comment: @AnmolGupta I guess that null returns nothing with the response, except the headers.

Comment: @sp00m No, it returns 200 OK and "No response received"

Comment: @AnmolGupta May you try with the `reason`, and using `void` as a return type (thus removing the `return null;` statement)?

Comment: @sp00m It does work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`@ResponseStatus`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html), if providing only a [`value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html#value--), [`HttpServletResponse.setStatus(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html?is-external=true#setStatus-int-) is used:

> **This method is used to set the return status code when there is no
>   error** (for example, for the SC_OK or SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY status
>   codes).
>
> If this method is used to set an error code, then the container's
>   error page mechanism will not be triggered. If there is an error and
>   the caller wishes to invoke an error page defined in the web
>   application, then **sendError(int, java.lang.String) must be used
>   instead**.

If providing a [`reason`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html#reason--) as well, then [`HttpServletResponse.sendError(int, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html?is-external=true#sendError-int-java.lang.String-) is used instead.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR")
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleConflict(Exception e) {
        // log me
    }
}
```